# How to get all xml/dom as text under a parent web element using selenium/python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario that requires working on a UI object displayed as a grid but the rows and columns are separate web elements contained in the xml / dom hierarchy consisting of multiple xpaths that can be parsed using a common pattern. 
All these elements contain texts corresponding to the column type.
Getting all these texts by webelement references one by one takes time.
Is there a way to get all this xml as text (or for at least one row in a single shot) to save extraction time by parsing entire xml inline.

For example, consider the bottom mentioned xml. How can i get all xml hierarchy underneath `<div[@class='table']>` as text to parse.

This is the sample example:

```
<div[@class='table']>
     <div[@class='rows']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               <div[@class='col']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text1</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text2</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text3</div[@class='element']>
                   ...
               </div[@class='col']>
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               <div[@class='col']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text1</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text2</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text3</div[@class='element']>
                   ...
               </div[@class='col']>
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
     </div[@class='rows']>
</div[@class='table']>
```

I need to fetch the xml/dom/div heirarchy as mentioned below:

```
    <div[@class='rows']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               <div[@class='col']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text1</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text2</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text3</div[@class='element']>
                   ...
               </div[@class='col']>
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               <div[@class='col']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text1</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text2</div[@class='element']>
                   <div[@class='element']>some_text3</div[@class='element']>
                   ...
               </div[@class='col']>
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
          <div[@class='row']>
               ...
          </div[@class='row']>
     </div[@class='rows']>
```

in one go.

Comment: Instead of handcrafted HTML update the question with text based actual HTML

Comment: Not sure why _Getting all these texts by webelement references one by one takes time_. Perhaps _Is there a way to get all this xml as text_ and _at least one row in a single shot_ are contradictory _usecases_. Please [edit the question](/posts/54454059/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried getting the top level table tag and then use `.text` and see what all you get? That should get you the text of the entire table to parse like you want. I don't think that's a good idea though.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - @DebanjanB - I have edited the question. I hope you understand but I can't provide the exact html due to company privacy reasons. I believe fetching xml/dom in one shot will take one operation O(1) while fetching multiple elements one by one will take as many operations O(n) as the number of elements grow. Please let me know if you feel otherwise.

Comment: @JeffC - getting the text will not work as the text could be multi-line and it will be more difficult to parse. Innerhtml will be easier to parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='table']").get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

The attribute [`outerHTML` will return you the element itself and all its child nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) - as they are present in the DOM.
I would recommend against the similar `innerHTML` as if the target element has a text subnode, you will receive it, but the result will not be a proper xml.

Comment: Works Perfect Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 WebElement element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='table']");
 String elementText = element.text;
```

In the string "elementText" you would be getting the whole texts that is present inside the table hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks but this would only return the text for the table - I would be needing the entire xml definition.

Comment: Then instead of fetching the xpath from the `@class='table'`. You can use the parent class name in it and then you would be getting the whole text.

Comment: Could you please provide the syntax for it like "some_web_element.get_contained_xml()" or something?

Comment: Do you need the div hierarchy as well ? Sorry, but want to understand what is the usecase for that, because then i would be able to help you better